# Regular Expression - issues with lower case and spaces

Tags: java, regex

My logic isn't always working because I am missing some regex parameter in order to ignore the cases and treat 2 spaces or 0 space as same as 1 space on the side of equal sign (e.g. "=" or "=  " should accept the same rule as "= "). All the code is below with demonstrations. Basically, the context is that I read a spreadsheet filled by a user with data organized by Data Element (DE) and Primary Data Set (PDS). All can be filled by its value or by Sub-fields (SF). So, in short terms, I read the input string looking for DE some_identity = some_value, or PDS some_identity = some_value or DE some_identity SF = some_value and just ignore the rest. It is working perfectly except for two issues: sometimes the user just fills the spreadsheet with two blank spaces "  " where it was expected to be just one " ". In other occasions, the user typed in lower case the identity label (e.g. sf).

1 Scenario (working as expected):
Input value
wholeLine  = “DE 3 = 00 Purchase PDS 158 SF 4 = BB DE 26 = 4511”
Output values
strTagDes = “de003(de003=00)-de026(de026=4511)-“
strTagPdss = “pds0158(pds0158pdss4=BB)-“

2 Scenario (not working as expected. Note sf is lower case):
Input value
wholeLine  = “DE 3 = 00 Purchase PDS 158 sf 4 = BB DE 26 = 4511”
Output values
strTagDes = “de003(de003=00)-de026(de026=4511)-“
strTagPdss = ““

3 Scenario (not working as expected. Note there is no space between DE and 26):
Input value
wholeLine  = “DE 3 = 00 Purchase PDS 158 SF 4 = BB DE26 = 4511”
Output values
strTagDes = “de003(de003=00)-“
strTagPdss = “pds0158(pds0158pdss4=BB)-“

4 Scenario (working as expected):
Input value
wholeLine  = “PDS 0017 = U0”
Output values
strTagDes = ““
strTagPdss = “pds0017(pds0017=U0)- “

5 Scenario (not working as expected. Note there is no space between 0017 and the “=’ signal):
Input value
wholeLine  = “PDS 0017= U0”
Output values
strTagDes = ““
strTagPdss = “”

6 Scenario (not working as expected. Note there are two spaces between the "=" signal and U0):
Input value
wholeLine  = “PDS 0017 =  U0”
Output values
strTagDes = ““
strTagPdss = “”

```
Pattern patternDE = Pattern.compile("DE \\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S+");
Matcher matcherDE = patternDE.matcher(wholeLine);
while (matcherDE.find()) {
       String strDe = "";
       String strDePdss = "";
       String wholeThing = matcherDE.group();
       String[] parts = wholeThing.split("=");
       if (parts[0].toUpperCase().contains("SF")) { // subfield present
              parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll(",","");
              String[] strValues = parts[0].trim().split(" ");
              strDe = "de" + String.format("%03d",Integer.parseInt(strValues[1]));
              String strPdss = "pdss" + strValues[3];
              strDePdss = strDe + "(" + strDe
                           + strPdss + "="
                           + parts[1].trim() + ")-";
       } else { // no subfield
              String[] strValues = parts[0].split(" ");
              strDe = "de" + String.format("%03d",                                             Integer.parseInt(strValues[1]));
              strDePdss = strDe + "(" + strDe + "=" + parts[1].trim()
                               + ")-";
           }
           strTagDes = strTagDes + strDePdss;
    }
Pattern patternPDS = Pattern.compile("PDS \\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S+");
Matcher matcherPDS = patternPDS.matcher(wholeLine);

while (matcherPDS.find()) {
       String strPds = "";
       String strPdsPdss = "";
       String wholeThing = matcherPDS.group();
       String[] parts = wholeThing.split("=");
       if (parts[0].toUpperCase().contains("SF")) { // subfield present
              parts[0] = parts[0].replaceAll(",","");
              String[] strValues = parts[0].trim().split(" ");
              strPds = "pds" + String.format( "%04d",Integer.parseInt(strValues[1]));
              String strPdss = "pdss" + strValues[3];
              strPdsPdss = strPds + "(" + strPds
                           + strPdss + "="
                           + parts[1].trim() + ")-";
       } else { // no subfield    
              String[] strValues = parts[0].split(" ");
              strPds = "pds"  + String.format( "%04d",Integer.parseInt(strValues[1]));
              strPdsPdss = strPds + "(" + strPds
                           + "=" + parts[1].trim()
                           + ")-";
       }
       strTagPdss = strTagPdss + strPdsPdss;
}

/*find the output in strTagDes and strTagPdss variables*/
```

Comment: Might want to format that code so it's somewhat readable....

Comment: Apologise, I just did it.

Comment: horrible formatting.. I tried to edit but gave up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to read due to poor formatting.

Comment: You'd need some regex to delete the superfluous lines in your question ;-) (edit: Wäre es auf Deutsch einfacher zu sagen, was Du wirklich meinst?).

Comment: Apologizes for the inconvenience. However, please, before freeze this question, take in account that only 5 minutes after I added my question I edited it in order to improve the visibility. I will pay more attention next time and I will thankful for help from everyone. Additionally, note the effort to make my question as clean as possible with scenarios and rich details added.

Answer (score 1):

For ignoring spaces around the equals sign, use `\s*=\s*`, or, as a Java String `"\\s*=\\s*"`. Also note that any white space in your pattern counts, i.e., if you write "a b" that actually means letter a, space, letter b. If you want to ignore white space, either write a quantifier with the space ("a *b" means letter a, zero to many spaces, letter b) or use `\s` which stands for white space (space, tab, ...) with a quantifier.

To match case-insensitively, pass the [CASE_INSENSITIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag to `Pattern.compile`.

Comment: Robert, thanks. By passing CASE_INSENSITIVE flag to Pattern.compile, I fixed the second scenario. However, I am still facing issues with spaces. I tried Pattern.compile("PDS \\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S*+") and I guess that it must be close to fix the scenario 6 because now I get the output strTagPdss = “pds0017(pds0017=)-“. The pattern brings the id label (i.e. pds0017) but the value (i.e. U0) is lost. For the scenario 3, I tried add * after DE and for scenario 5 I tried add * after PDS \\d with nothing changed in output. I am very limited in RegEx. If you need any further info, let me know it.

Comment: Robert, your explanation is clear and make a lot of sense to me but I am still stuck. Let'me narrow the issue to a simple example: wholeLine = “DE3 = 00". Note there is no space between DE and 3. Then I try in Pattern.compile: "DE* \\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S+", "DE*\\* \\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S+", "DE* \\s *\\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S+", "DE \\s*\\d+,?( SF \\d+)* = \\S+"